# Stochastic process as integral over window function

Tags: stochastic-processes, itos-lemma

Consider the following stochastic integral  of a deterministic function $f(t,s)$ with respect to the Wiener process $W_s$:

$$\int_0^\infty f(t,s) d W_s$$

My questions are:

1. Is such an integral suitably well-defined that it defines a stochastic process $Y_t$?
2. If so, is there a simple expression for $dY_t$?

I'm aware that the Ito integral with $t$ as the upper limit in the integration defines a stochastic process, but it is unclear what happens in this more general case (we can recover the usual case by $f(t,s)=f(s)(1-\Theta(s-t))$, where $\Theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function). Apologies in advance if this question has already been answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process
$$
Y_t=\int_0^\infty f(t,s)\,d W_s
$$
is well defined when the usual condition $P[\int_0^\infty f^2(t,s) ds<\infty]=1$ holds which in your deterministic case boils down to $\int_0^\infty f^2(t,s) ds<\infty$. When $f(t,s)$ is differentiable in $t$ and $\int_0^\infty \partial_t f^2(t,s) ds<\infty$ then
$$
dY_t=\left(\int_0^\infty \partial_t f(t,s)\,dW_s\right)\,dt\,.
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I ended up asking the same question on math.stackexchange here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302036/stochastic-process-as-an-ito-integral-over-time-dependent-integrand-without-t?noredirect=1#comment8960021_4302036 . I would be happy to select this as an answer both here and there if you are willing to post it over?

Comment: @broken_urn . I posted it over.